# new facebook T_OBJECT_OPERATOR error

Tags: php, facebook

i get this error:

> syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR

in...

```
$this->loadState();
if ($this->isValidRedirect()) {
  $params = array(
    'client_id' => FacebookSession::_getTargetAppId($this->appId),
    'redirect_uri' => $this->redirectUrl,
    'client_secret' =>
      FacebookSession::_getTargetAppSecret($this->appSecret),
    'code' => $this->getCode()
  );
  $response = (new FacebookRequest(
    FacebookSession::newAppSession($this->appId, $this->appSecret),
    'GET',
    '/oauth/access_token',
    $params
  ))->execute()->getResponse();
  if (isset($response['access_token'])) {
    return new FacebookSession($response['access_token']);
  }
}
return null;
```

this is the line of error: `))->execute()->getResponse();`

Comment: Is it possible that your php version is prior to 5.4?

Comment: my php version is 5.3

Answer (score 0):

As I though, your PHP version is 5.3 (< 5.4).
In your code you're trying to access class members on instantiation, an option that was introduced only on PHP 5.4.

> Class member access on instantiation has been added, e.g. (new
>   Foo)->bar().

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Therefore, you have to change your code and separate that part into 2 steps, as the following:

```
$fbRequest = new FacebookRequest(
    FacebookSession::newAppSession($this->appId, $this->appSecret),
    'GET',
    '/oauth/access_token',
    $params
  );

$response = $fbRequest->execute()->getResponse();
```

Comment: Please let me know if is solved your problem (as I believe it should).

Comment: yes solved but now other error,i think that my php version is guilty...... thanks anyway!

Comment: If it helped you solve your problem, please approve my answer.

Comment: Changing a single line of code will not solve this. The PHP SDK v4 uses features that only became available with PHP 5.4 internally a lot, so using a PHP version >= 5.4 is a requirement.

Comment: yes Ofir Baruch your answer solve the problem with this code thanks!

Comment: Then please accept my answer. Please notice to @CBroe's comment and consider using a Facebook PHP SDK perior to v4 or upgrade your php version to (at least) 5.4.